# Is there a way to make pip ask for confirmation before install a package?

Tags: python, pip

Before installing a package, I want to know all the dependencies that will be installed/updated/downgraded.

Can `pip install` prompt a confirmation message like what `pip uninstall` do?

```
pip uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.22.3
Uninstalling numpy-1.22.3:
  Would remove:
    /home//bin/f2py
    /home//bin/f2py3
    /home//bin/f2py3.9
    /home//lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.22.3.dist-info/*
    /home//lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy.libs/libgfortran-040039e1.so.5.0.0
    /home//lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-2f7c42d4.3.18.so
    /home//lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy.libs/libquadmath-96973f99.so.0.0.0
    /home//lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/*
Proceed (Y/n)?
```

I have searched a lot and didn't find a trivial way, so any workaround that can tell me the information(packages will be installed/updated/downgraded) without actually installing a package is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look into virtual python environments so that you can keep the python dependencies separate between different projects.  This may solve a lot of your pain.  For example https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: Even within the same virtual environment there might be dependency conflicts between installed packages. Unfortunately `pip` doesn't attempt to resolve any conflicts. You should use something more advanced such as `pipenv` or `poetry` for that.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for your advice. I am using conda a lot. Is `pipenv` or `poetry` a better choice than `conda`?

Comment: @Jessica Thanks, I am using conda for virtual env but still want that feature.

Comment: You have all `pip` options [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/), looking through there, there is no command line argument that we can give to `pip` that controls this behaviour, there has been a call to add this [for quite some time](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/53).

Comment: @hsc if you are using `conda`, then I would suggest to stick to using that as much as possible, as it already has the functionality you need.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks for your advice, initially I thought the `dry run` question is different from mine(before this question is asked), but I will mark this question as dup now.